# UV unwrapping for textile pattern

Tags: uv, texture-coordinates

Hello amazing blender community! I have a kind of reverse-engineering issue. I am working in blender to prototype a physical artwork which looks like a landscape covered with textile. The landscape occupies a 16x16f square footprint.
See the quick render attached. [image]

I need to unwrap the 3d model of the textile to a 1 to 1 fabric pattern so I can work on the actual textile design and production. It must be precise 1:1 proportionately without any distortions. I understand that it will have a complex form, and I will need to sew parts together.
I have been experimenting with making seams in different positions and unwrapping, but I feel like I am pretty much eyeballing it, and that is not a way to go.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions how to achieve this... I have been trying to figure it out for a few days with no recourse. Any tips will be appreciated!

Comment: Textile is partly stretchy, so some smaller distortions can be form. If you need to split object into continue parts without stretching you can use [Export Paper Model addon](https://blenderartists.org/t/export-paper-model/476597) ... I haven't use it for a long time, but I guess it can calculate optimal seams for you too) ... start with some simpler (lowly) model to test it.